# Having an Issue with exec() function

Tags: python, string, variables

I have encountered a major roadblock in the User Interface in my Python Minigame. I am using Python 3.3, and what I would like to do would be to use the `exec` function (as I can't find an alternative) to combine string 'x' and 'y' to edit that specific variable.

The code I am using is below.

```
exec('x'+'y'+" = 'x'")
# This is to edit variable xy in theory #
```

Comment: This seems like an XY problem, pardon the pun.

Comment: What exactly *is* the problem? You don't say what you expected, or what happened. Why don't you just write `"xy = 'x'"`?

Comment: This would be an excellent time to learn to use a dict, or lists, or some other useful data structure. `exec` is not the answer.

Comment: I don't understand...the code above functions pretty well.

Comment: So... You have two letters (`x` and `y`), and you want to edit the variable `xy`? What problem are you facing? The code you have posted should work well...

Comment: Your code will execute the python code:

`xy = 'x'`

It assigns the value `'x'` to the variable `xy`. That's apparently not what you want it to do. What do you want it to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

```
exec('x'+'='+'y'+" = 'x'")
print(x)#confirms that x and y = x
print(y)
```

If you want to edit the variable xy, do this:

```
exec('xy'+" = 'x'")
print(xy)
```

Hope this helped.

**UPDATE**

To simplify the `exec()` do this:

For x and y:

```
exec("x  = y = 'x'")
```

For xy:

```
exec("xy = 'x'")
```